# Java RMI connection failure

Tags: java, rmi

I keep getting a failure to connect error when using JAVA RMI

My code:
    //mathServer//

```
import java.rmi.*;
import java.rmi.Naming.*;
import java.rmi.server.*;
import java.rmi.registry.*;
import java.net.*;
import java.util.*;



interface mathInterface extends Remote
{
 public int add(int a,int b) throws RemoteException;
 public int subt(int a,int b) throws RemoteException;
 public int mult(int a,int b) throws RemoteException;
 public int div(int a,int b) throws RemoteException;
}

public class mathServer extends UnicastRemoteObject implements
mathInterface

{
            /**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
            public mathServer() throws RemoteException
            {
                            System.out.println("Initializing Server");


}
public int add(int a,int b)
{
                            return(a+b);
            }
            public int subt(int a,int b)
                {
                                            return(a-b);
            }
            public int mult(int a,int b)
                {
                                            return(a*b);
            }
            public int div(int a,int b)
                {
                                            return(a/b);
            }
            public static void main(String args[])
            {
                            try
                            {
                            mathServer ms=new mathServer();
                            java.rmi.Naming.rebind("MathServ",ms);
                            System.out.println("Server Ready");
                }
                catch(RemoteException RE)
                {
                                            System.out.println("Remote Server Error:"+ RE.getMessage());
                                            System.exit(0);
                            }
                            catch(MalformedURLException ME)
                            {
                                            System.out.println("Invalid URL!!");
                            }
            }
```

}

When I run it I get the following error:

```
Remote Server Error:Connection refused to host: 192.168.56.1; nested exception is: 
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
```

The rest of the code for the client  is:

```
//mathClient//
import java.rmi.*;  //this packaged performs OO equivalent of remote         procedure calls -  asterisks used to import the whole package rather than a     specific class
import java.rmi.registry.*; // bootstrap naming service that is used by RMI servers on the same host to bind remote objects to names
import java.awt.*; //gui toolkit
import java.awt.event.*; //events for the GUI toolkit

public class 


mathClient extends Frame implements ActionListener //Frame is the GUI toolkit basic class
{
            Button B1=new Button("Sum"); //creates new button on the calculator
            Button B2=new Button("Subtract");
            Button B3=new Button("Multiply");
            Button B4=new Button("Divide");
            Button B5=new Button("Enter");//creates new button on the calculator needs to have bounds set before active
            Label l1=new Label("Number 1"); //creates a label for the text entry fields
            Label l2=new Label("Number 2");
            Label l3=new Label("Result");
            Label l4=new Label("TextEntry");
            TextField t1=new TextField(20);  //creates text entry fields needs to have bounds set before active
            TextField t2=new TextField(20);
            TextField t3=new TextField(20);
            TextField t4=new TextField(20);
            public mathClient()
            {
                            super("Calculator");
                            setLayout(null);
                            l1.setBounds(20,50,55,25);
                            add(l1);
                            l2.setBounds(20,100,55,25);
                            add(l2);
                            l3.setBounds(20,150,55,25);
                            add(l3);
                            t1.setBounds(150,50,100,25);
                            add(t1);
                            t2.setBounds(150,100,100,25);
                            add(t2);
                            t3.setBounds(150,150,100,25);
                            add(t3);
                            t4.setBounds(150,300,100,50); //sets the size of the text box as per button size above
                            add(t4); //add the text box, can comment out to hide
                            B1.setBounds(20,200,80,25); //set size of the buttons, again need to identify dimensions
                            add(B1);
                            B2.setBounds(100,200,80,25);
                            add(B2);
                            B3.setBounds(180,200,80,25);
                            add(B3);
                            B4.setBounds(260,200,80,25);
                            add(B4);
                            B5.setBounds(320,200,80,25);  //this sets the location of the button on the screen, the first number is horizontal position, the second is the vertical position, third is the width of the button and 4th is the height of the button
                            add(B5); //this is used to show the button, comment it out to hide it from view
                            B1.addActionListener(this); //creates a listener for the button push
                            B2.addActionListener(this);
                            B3.addActionListener(this);
                            B4.addActionListener(this);
                            B5.addActionListener(this);
                            addWindowListener(
                                            new WindowAdapter()
                                                            {
                                                                            public void windowClosing(WindowEvent e)//used for closing the calculator window
                                                                            {
                                                                                            System.exit(0);
                                                                            }
                                                            }
                            );
            }
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent AE)//checks when an action occurs in the wid=ndow
            {
                                            if(AE.getSource()==B1)//checks which button has had an acionable event
                                            {
                                                            sum();//calls the relevant method, in this case it sums the inputs
                                            }
                                            else if(AE.getSource()==B2)
                                            {
                                                            subt();
                                            }
                                            else if(AE.getSource()==B3)
                                            {
                                                            mult();
                                            }
                                            else if(AE.getSource()==B4)
                                            {
                                                             div();
                                            }
                            }
                            public void sum() // the method for the sum button
                            {
                                            int i=Integer.parseInt(t1.getText()); //used for converting the entry from text fields from text to int
                                            int j=Integer.parseInt(t2.getText()); // used for converting from the 2nd text field
                                            int val; //used for result i expect
                                            try
                                            {
                                                            String ServerURL="MathServ";
                                                            mathInterface MI=(mathInterface)Naming.lookup(ServerURL);
                                                            val=MI.add(i,j);
                                                            t3.setText(""+val);
                                            }
                                            catch(Exception ex)
                                            {
                                                            System.out.println("Exception:"+ex);
                                            }
                            }
                            public void subt()
                            {
                                            int i=Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
                                            int j=Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());
                                            int val;
                                            try
                                            {
                                                            String ServerURL="MathServ";
                                                            mathInterface MI=(mathInterface)Naming.lookup(ServerURL);
                                                            val=MI.subt(i,j);
                                                            t3.setText(""+val);
                                            }
                                            catch(Exception ex)
                                            {
                                                            System.out.println("Exception:"+ex);
                                            }
                            }
                            public void mult()
                            {
                                            int i=Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
                                            int j=Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());
                                            int val;
                                            try
                                            {
                                                            String ServerURL="MathServ";
                                                            mathInterface MI=(mathInterface)Naming.lookup(ServerURL);
                                                            val=MI.mult(i,j);
                                                            t3.setText(""+val);
                                            }
                                            catch(Exception ex)
                                            {
                                                            System.out.println("Exception:"+ex);
                                            }
                            }
                            public void div()
                            {
                                            int i=Integer.parseInt(t1.getText());
                                            int j=Integer.parseInt(t2.getText());
                                            int val;
                                            try
                                            {
                                                            String ServerURL="MathServ";
                                                            mathInterface MI=(mathInterface)Naming.lookup(ServerURL);
                                                            val=MI.div(i,j);
                                                            t3.setText(""+val);
                                            }
                                            catch(Exception ex)
                                            {
                                                            System.out.println("Exception:"+ex);
                                            }
                            }
                            public static void main(String args[])
                            {
                                            mathClient MC=new mathClient();
                                            MC.setVisible(true);
                                            MC.setSize(600,500);
                            };
            }
```

I have tried setting the etc`hosts file but there seems to be no problem there. I am not sure why it is trying to connect to the IP 192.168.56.1 instead of 127.0.0.1

ANy help would be appreciated, this is the first time I have done anything server side so I amy be missing something obvious but I have tried the other solutions for RMI failing to connect.

Comment: Please format this illegible mess properly.

Comment: can you clarify how I would format it further?

Answer (score 1):

You haven't started the RMI Registry.

Comment: thanks, I had done this but it didn't seem to do anything, retried this morning and now I am getting different errors but at least that is progress.

Comment: So you thought you had done it but you hadn't.

Comment: I had run javaw rmiregistry from command line but it did nothing, when I tried from another machine it started rmiregistry and resulted in a different error. So I had done it but I think the issue related to ports on my laptop not being open.

Comment: If you got this error you didn't start the Registry, period. NB The RMI registry has to run in the same host that is calling `bind()`.